# encode issues python word document

Tags: python, ms-word

i have a huge **word document file** that has more than 10,000 lines in it and it contains random empty lines and also weird characters, and i want to save it as a .txt or a .fasta file to read each line as string, and run through my program to pull out only the fasta headers and their sequences.

i have searched online and all of the posts about encoding issues just make it more confusing for me.

so far  i have tried:

**1)** save the word document file as a .txt file with unicode(UTF-8) option. and ran my code below, about 1000 lines were outputted until it hit an error.

```
with open('TemplateMaster2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fin, open('OnlyFastaseq.fasta', 'w') as fout:
for line in fin:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        fout.write(line)
        fout.write(next(fin))
```

error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode chracter '\uf044' in position 11: character maps to <undefined>
```

**2)**  save the word document file as a .txt file with unicode(UTF-8) option. about 1000 some lines were outputted until it hit a different error.

```
with open('TemplateMaster2.txt') as fin, open('OnlyFastaseq.fasta', 'w') as fout:
for line in fin:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        fout.write(line)
        fout.write(next(fin))
```

error message:

```
unicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' code can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5664: character map to <undefined>
```

I can try different options for saving that word document as a .txt file but there are too many options and i am not sure what the problem really is. Should i save the word document as .txt with the option of 'unicode' or 'unicode(Big-Endian)', or 'unicode(UTF-7)', or 'Unicode(UTF-8)', or 'US-ASCII', etc.

Comment: Is the problem solved or still open?

Comment: open , i'm not sure why i got a vote down, i feel discouraged to ask questions now.

Comment: The site is about learning, so don't get discouraged by down votes. Did you try the code below? What error did it give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing which seems to be missing is `encoding='utf-8'` in your open statement for `fout`.

```
with open('TemplateMaster2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin, open('OnlyFastaseq.fasta', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            fout.write(line)
            seq = next(fin)
            fout.write(seq)
```

Did you double check if your sequences are really every time only in one line?